# Is It possible to expand FCM in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I Would like to ask is it possible to expand notification in flutter FCM notification if the text is already overflowed?

This is sample code which I used for notification:

```
void initFirebase() {
    _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(
            sound: true, badge: true, alert: true, provisional: false));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      debugPrint('Settings registered: $settings');
    });
  }

  void configFirebase() {
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print(message);
        final FirebaseModel dataModel = FirebaseModel.fromJson(message);
        await notifHandler.showNotif(dataModel);
        notifHandler.onNotifRefresh(dataModel.data?.action);
        if (dataModel?.data?.action == AppString.CONFIRM_REDEEM_POINT) {
          notifHandler.onSelectNotification(dataModel?.data?.action ?? '');
        }
      },
//      onBackgroundMessage: _onBackgroundMessage,
      onResume: _showFirebaseNotif,
      onLaunch: _showFirebaseNotif,
    );
  }
```

This is the result that I got[image]

Answer (score 3):

yes it is possible you need to provide style information as BigTextStyleInformation('') in AndroidNotificationDetails like this

```
        final androidChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'your channel id',
          'your channel name',
          'your channel description',
          importance: Importance.Max,
          priority: Priority.High,
          ongoing: true,
    
          styleInformation: BigTextStyleInformation(''),
        );
```